# Write to Debug Console using Visual Studio Code for C# Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to display a message for the user during a unit test, and have found that is available [in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms404699(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) using `Test Context`. `System.Console.WriteLine` and `Debug.WriteLine` both don't seem to work.

Just as a note, I'm running using the `Debug Test` option which I believe is available through the VSCode C# extension:

[image: debug test image]

Comment: the linked article is 12 years old, can you find a version related to the latest C# version

Answer (score 1):

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test");`

seems to work, a coworker figured it out

[image]